# Why use integers for tokens?

Tags: compiler-construction

Is there any good reason for using numbers for identifying tokens, nowadays? I am following `Crafting a Compiler`.

The code the author presents is here:

```
public class Token {
    public final static int ID = 0, FLTDCL = 1, INTDCL = 2, PRINT = 3,
            ASSIGN = 4, PLUS = 5, MINUS = 6, EOF = 7, INUM = 8, FNUM = 9;

    public final static String[] token2str = new String[] { "id", "fltdcl",
            "intdcl", "print", "assign", "plus", "minus", "$", "inum", "fnum" };

    public final int type;
    public final String val;

    public Token(int type) {
        this(type, "");
    }

    public Token(int type, String val) {
        this.type = type;
        this.val = val;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Token type\t" + token2str[type] + "\tval\t" + val;
    }
}
```

Instead of using the ugly arrays, wouldn't it be smarter to modify the constructors to accept strings for the `type` variable instead of integers? Then we could get rid of

```
    public final static int ID = 0, FLTDCL = 1, INTDCL = 2, PRINT = 3,
            ASSIGN = 4, PLUS = 5, MINUS = 6, EOF = 7, INUM = 8, FNUM = 9;
```

or is it needing later, being that using a string instead would be worse?

Comment: I think it's just for speed -- compilers really need all the speed they can get, and using strings hurts cache locality. But there might also be another (better) reason, I don't know (hence why I didn't post this as an answer).

Comment: The cryptic identifiers are bad enough, but at least he could have typed the string versions out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several benefits:

- It's faster, since comparing two integers takes (in your average compiled language) only a few instructions, while comparing strings takes O(*n*) time where *n* is the length of the larger token. [Compilers need this extra bit of speed](http://xkcd.com/303/).
- In C, C++ and Java, you can `switch` on an `int` but not on a string.
- Mistyping a token name will be a compile-time error instead of a hard-to-debug runtime error.

Comment: In fact, I recommend defining a bunch of constants whenever a string turns out to be a member of a small, fixed, finite set. It's both faster *and* safer.

Comment: "Mistyping a token name will be a compile-time error instead of a hard-to-debug runtime error." I doubt it'd be a hard to debug runtime error. And you could create a subclass for each token, thus still having compile time errors.